# Issue removing margin with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

I cannot seem to succeed to completely fill a horizontal space with a div.
There is always a little space at the right, left, top and bottom.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpdeoL1v/1/)

I am currently using:

CSS:

```css
.section{
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;    
}
#section-1,#section-3{
   background-color: #ddd;    
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="section-1" class="section">
  <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the `p` tag of the browser causing this. http://jsfiddle.net/gpdeoL1v/6/ Use a browser reset css instead for a cleaner fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also put `margin: 0` on `body`

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

What is generally done is setting `margin` and `padding` both to `0` on both `html` and `body` to make it work perfectly cross-browser.

```
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's actually because of the `margin` for the `body`. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpdeoL1v/5/). I've added this style to the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I think I mistook what margins do. I thought that it controls the outer margin instead the inner margin.